# QQuickWindow:renderTargetId() replacement in Qt 6.0?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt-quick, qt6

`QQuickWindow::renderTargetId()` is removed in Qt 6.0, because underlying graphics API now may be different from OpenGL.

There is now `QQuickRenderTarget` which is abstract from graphics API, but I can't obtain FBO ID from it when I use OpenGL (I call `QQuickWindow::setGraphicsApi(QSGRendererInterface::OpenGL)` in `main()`).

So I render my scene in my offscreen FBO, but when I want to render a result into the FBO, created by a QQuickWindow, which is not the default FBO with ID = 0 (QQuickWindow creates an FBO with ID = 1 right now), because my QQuickWindow is used by a QQuickWidget embedded into a QMainWindow (so I put Qt Quick and QML into a QWidget-based UI).

I may query the current set FBO ID via OpenGL API, of course, before I call `glBindFramebuffer()` to render into my own FBO, but I would like to read QQuickWindow's FBO ID using it's API, is there any way?

Comment: Can you use QQuickRenderControl for this purpose?

Comment: @peppe Sorry, I don't understand how QQuickRenderControl may help me to obtain QQuickWindow's offscreen framebuffer ID so I can render my stuff there after I changed bound target framebuffer to some one created by me.

Comment: It was (well, still is) unclear to me what you need to do: is it just rendering Qt Quick content into an OpenGL FBO that you control? (Once Qt Quick has rendered itself, then you're in charge and do whatver you need with that FBO?)

Comment: @peppe I wanted to do the opposite: to render my stuff (basically copying an image from my own FBO) into the QQuickWindow's FBO, created by Qt. But I can't obtain the FBO's id.

Comment: QQuickWindow does not use any FBO "out of the box". It renders directly on a window's surface. If you want to hook into that, you can connect to some of QQuickWindow's signals and then draw your stuff before/after QQuickWindow itself draws Qt Quick content. If I'm off, please again, elaborate a bit more on your use case...